# How create one-to-one relationship between identity user and my Employee table

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity-2

I'm trying to create an one-to-one relationship between my AspNetUser (ApplicationUser class) table and my Employee table.

The problem is:

- My application has so many relationships with my Employee table, so I can't create a composite key.

What I've tried:

- I tried to use unique index, but entity framework doesn't Support indexes.
- I tried to put the foreign key in ApplicationUser class, but I guess asp.net identity doesn't support composite key in AspNetUsers table.

Here is a example of what I expect to implement:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
    {
        public ApplicationUser()
            : base()
        {
            PreviousUserPasswords = new List<PreviousPassword>();
        }
        public virtual IList<PreviousPassword> PreviousUserPasswords { get; set; }

        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("EMPLOYEE")]
    public class Employee
    {
        [Key, Column("ID")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Column("ID_IDIOM")]
        public int IdIdiom { get; set; }
        [Column("USER_LOGIN")]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Column("NAME")]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Column("EMAIL")]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Column("ACTIVE")]
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        [Column("EMPLOYEE_TYPE")]
        public short EmployeeType { get; set; }
        [Column("SHOW_TUTORIAL")]
        public bool ShowTutorial { get; set; }

        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    }
```

Any idea will help a lot.

PS.: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Are these in different contexts? If you're application context inherits from the identity context, then you should be able to reference employee in there (foreign key, not composite key). If they are separate, then you will need to create an ApplicationUser class in your non-identity context.

Comment: @SteveGreene It's the same context. But when I create a foreign key without using a composite key, EF think it's a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: thanks man. It worked. But just worked after I run my application in an empty database, then I moved the identity tables to my existing database. I recommend you to write your comment like an answer so I can accept as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be configured with the fluent api if your application context inherits from IdentityDbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
   .HasRequired(e => e.User)
   .WithRequiredDependent(u => u.Employee);
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#RequiredToRequired